# Value of an array is returned as undefined from recursive function. Why? How could one fix this?

Tags: arrays, recursion, undefined

I am trying to push something into an array in a recursive function and return changed array. For some reason whenever recursion is being triggered the returned value is undefined. Simplified example here:

```
const some_array = ['abc','def'];
let count = 0;

const recur = () => {
    some_array.push('ghi');
    count++;
    if(count===2) return some_array;
    recur();
}
```

So can anyone tell why returned value is undefined? How to fix it?
Obviously you can smell that I am a beginner so I beg for indulgence.

Answer (score 0):

In which case do you really need the return value?
If you call `recur()` once, and then print out the values of `some_array`, you can see that the array already contains the updated value.
So instead of accessing the return value, you can simply access `some_array`

Comment: Thanks, It turned out that I need to put return keyword before calling recursive function.